# Print char of string uppercase if it is a vowel and lowercase if it is a consonant

Tags: string, j

I am trying to come up with a verb that will take a string as input
and printa character uppercase if it is a vowel i.e. (aeiou) or lowercase
if it is a consonant.

```
s=:'authority'
t=:<&>s
│a│u│t│h│o│r│i│t│y│ NB. boxed s
```

Expected output is : AUthOrIty
I tried writing verb using control flow structure using e.(membership) to test if a char
is a vowel and then `echo toupper s` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to box on individual characters. `"0` will apply an atom at a time and in this case your characters are atoms.

I would use `e.` to check to see if a character is a vowel and if it is apply `toupper` by using the `^:` power conjunction on the test `e.&vow`

```
   s=:'authority'
   vow=:'aeiou' NB. define vowels
   
   toupper^:(e.&vow)"0  s 
AUthOrIty
```

Answer (score 1):

As bob says, there is no reason to box individual characters.  I would prefer to use dataflow over control flow here: generate the complete uppercased string, and then select the appropriately-cased characters using `}`:

```
   s=:'authority'
   s ,: toupper s
authority
AUTHORITY
   s e.'aeiou'
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   (s e.'aeiou')} s ,: toupper s
AUthOrIty
```

See [nuvoc](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlyrt).

A functionally equivalent alternative using `{`:

```
   s ,. toupper s
aA
uU
tT
hH
oO
rR
iI
tT
yY
   (s e.'aeiou') {"_1 s ,. toupper s
AUthOrIty
```

Comment: The approach shown by you is interesting and clever. laminate/append is useful along with from/select and I will try to use it when addressing J tasks in future.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
   (tolower`toupper)@.(e.&'aeiou')"0 'aaaabbBBCCccceeee'
AAAAbbbbcccccEEEE
```

See: https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/atdot